# There was an error reflecting property 'Lists'

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize a custom object into xml with this code:

```
MatchList matchList = converter.Convert(excelStream);
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MatchList));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, matchList);
string serializedXml = stringWriter.ToString();
txtResult.Text = serializedXml;
```

However I get the exception above in the 2nd line:

The matchlist object is defined as:

```
public class MatchList
{
   public Header Header { get; set; }

   [XmlArray("Lists")]
   [XmlArrayItem("List")]
   public virtual List<List> Lists { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the internal <List> is a custom object, not c# List object.

Comment: what exception did you get?

Comment: Please show the code of `List` class. That said, to avoid confusion, why not using another name than List?

Comment: By any chance, is your `List` non-public? If I recall correctly, `XmlSerializer` requires all objects be public. EDIT: Woah, didn't realize your type was `List<List>`... can't... but... ****explodes****

Comment: You need to post `List` in the `T` of `List<T>` for us to help you. Is `T` in the `List<T>` a generic type?

Comment: @LukeHennerley I don't think `T` is generic (otherwise the code wouldn't compile), but I suspect that `T` (or a class referenced by `T`) isn't publicly accessible/serializable for the `XmlSerializer`. (From now on, I propose to refer to Luis' custom `List` class as `T`!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[XmlArray("Lists")]
[XmlArrayItem("List")]
public virtual List<object> Lists { get; set; }
```

and add mark knownTypeAttribute with serializable types as `object`

Comment: May I ask what exactly is the problem here? Is the `XmlSerializer` just tripping over itself with types having the same class short-name?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a property in your object that you don't need to serialize, add the attribute

```
[XmlIgnore]
```

on top of it. To find the problematic property, dig in by click the "View Details..." in the exception message,  and keep clicking the "Inner exception" all the way.